# Create multidimensional array from foreach in a function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to create multidimensional array using foreach in a function.

Here is my code:

```
$colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
$sizes = ['s', 'm', 'l', 'xl'];
$materials = ['cotton', 'silk'];
foreach ( $colors as $color ){
    foreach ( $sizes as $size ){
        foreach ( $materials as $material ){
            $result[] = "{$color}:{$size}:{$material}";
        }
    }
}
```

The output suppose to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red:s:cotton
    [1] => red:s:silk
    [2] => red:m:cotton
    [3] => red:m:silk
    [4] => red:l:cotton
    [5] => red:l:silk
    [6] => red:xl:cotton
    [7] => red:xl:silk
    [8] => green:s:cotton
    [9] => green:s:silk
    [10] => green:m:cotton
    [11] => green:m:silk
    [12] => green:l:cotton
    [13] => green:l:silk
    [14] => green:xl:cotton
    [15] => green:xl:silk
    [16] => blue:s:cotton
    [17] => blue:s:silk
    [18] => blue:m:cotton
    [19] => blue:m:silk
    [20] => blue:l:cotton
    [21] => blue:l:silk
    [22] => blue:xl:cotton
    [23] => blue:xl:silk
)
```

Yes, indeed I got what I want. But what if I want to add more arrays? Looping an array in a loop in a loop in a loop doesn't seems convenient at all.

Is there a function like `merge_it( $arr1, $arr2, $arr3, ... )` so it does all the jobs for me?

Comment: you are not creating any multidimensional array, yours it's a unidimensional array with concatenated values.

Answer (score 0):

In case the arrays all have the same size could simply do this:

http://pastebin.com/50zD6KnW

Reference isn't needed as it's just reading the arrays anyways. I haven't benchmarked huge arrays when it comes to this matter, but in your case it should work just great.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. There is a PHP function to merge arrays, [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), which unions as many arrays as you use as arguments.  However keep in mind that you are not creating multidimensional arrays, instead you are creating a unidimensional array with concatenated values.  And the only way to add values to be concatenated is by iterating and concatenating, then pushing the composed value to the expected array.